# How can I install GeoIP on my shared hosting?

Tags: php, geolocation, geoip

I have succesfully installed net_geoIP with the built in PEAR extension installer for apache but it does not do what I need it to do. I want to install GeoIP but I don't know how I would add it to my shared hosting. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to ask your hosting provider to install it for you. If they are not willing to do it, you may need a new hosting provider.